# Dilemma with Partition Key choice

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

One of our tables is over 200gb and the old records are hardly ever queried, and this makes me think partitioning is a good solution, however I am having trouble figuring out which column to use as a Partition Key for a table.

We have 2 tables as follows (names and structures are altered for confidentiality):

- `transactions` table - with a transaction ID,
- `checks` table - With the schema `(id, transcation_id, created_at, metadata, last_updated_at)` there can be multiple different checks with for a given `transaction_id`

As part of data aggregation we write a summarized version of the checks into a single column in the `transactions` table. The way we do this aggregation is by running an `UPDATE` on `transactions` table with joins on the checks table filtering by `last_updated_at` to only check for checks that have been updated recently.

Users however query using `created_at` in the `checks` table, and also `last_updated_at` could potentially change for a given row (although not likely).

Which one should I use as partition key? `created_at` or `last_updated_at`?

Comment: Why partition at all?  It i hard to choose a partition key without knowing that.

Comment: The table is very large and the older records are hardly ever used.

Comment: Large size is not inherently a reason to partition.  That the oldest data is rarely used also is not inherently a reason to partition, though it could form the basis of a reason.  Is the new data naturally clustered in the table?  In all the indexes?

Comment: The data is inserted in order so the newest data is clustered. I'm not sure I understand your question about the indexes in this context. We have index on multiple columns including a `kind` column an a column for IDs of rows in other tables (FK not setup for these) which can span across multiple partitions (regardless of which column I go with)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most queries become slower with partitioning.

The exceptions I know are:

- a query that needs a sequential scan, but contains the partitioning key in the `WHERE` clause
- a query that joins two partitioned tables, and the join condition matches the partition key for both
- a query that groups and aggregates by the partitioning key

So you should rather consider how data expire. Partition your tables so that you can get rid of old, obsolete data by dropping partitions.

Comment: These are exactly the kinds of queries that we do on this table, however the batch data aggregations and the user queries would use different columns in `WHERE/GROUP BY`  clauses, which is why I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: So you want partitioning for performance, not to discard old data? Only some of your queries will have the potential to get faster, so pick the most important ones and test. Also consider other performance tuning measures like indexes.

Comment: Thanks, it's basically what I thought I'd need to do but wanted to confirm if I was missing anything.